# List of safe mobile browsers

Tags: testing, mobile, browser

I am looking for a list of mobile browsers that should be considered while testing a website on mobile.

We already test the website on the following browsers:

safari/chrome on IOS.
Opera Mobile, Opera min, Android browser, Chrome and Firefox on Android

I want to know if we are missing out any important ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer for Windows phone 8/7.

Coast, Dolphin, Maxthon Web Browser for IOS.

LinkBubble, Dolphin, Maxthon Web Browser for Android.

And the Puffin Browser for IOS and Andrioid can be really useful as it allows flash media. And don't forget to check websites like http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1&qpcustomb=1 regualary as the Browsers with the highest market share and change quite quickly.

Hope this has helped :)

Comment: Based on the list of Market share. I guess we were missing IE Mobile. Thanks for your help